# What does my WCF service expect the request data to look like?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a WCF-hosted service right now which is self-hosted and defined like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/device")]
void updateDeviceLevel(ZDevice device);
```

The ZDevice class looks like this:

```
public class ZDevice {
    public bool? newPowerState { get; set; }
    public int nodeId {get; set;}
}
```

I have a simple Mac client which consumes the service by using an http post. It posts `{"newLevel":27,"nodeId":6}` to the `\devices` url and .NET magically stuffs the values into a ZDevice object for me. All is well here.

Now however, I need to add some basic security to the mix. I've done this by adding a new parameter and some "RequestWrapping" to the method call:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/device")]
void updateDeviceLevel(string password, ZDevice device);
```

What I'm trying to do now is figure out what syntax the server is expecting from the consuming clients. I'd hoped that posting in `{"password":"somepwd", "newLevel":27,"nodeId":6}` would work, but .NET is no longer able to "deserialize" that into the ZDevice object like it did before.

Anyone got some suggestions for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
{"password":"somepwd", "device": {"newLevel":27,"nodeId":6}}
```

Each property on the JSON object has a value; and in the case of `device` it's just a new object.

Note that in your `ZDevice` class you called it `newPowerState`, but in JSON you are calling it `newLevel`. In your class it's also a bool, but in JSON you are assigning it an int. Something isn't matching up.

Based on your C#, I'd expect it to look like this:

```
{"password":"somepwd", "device": {"newPowerState":true,"nodeId":6}}
```

The property names in your JSON object should match the parameter / property names in C#.

Comment: DOH! I thought I had tried that, but I did "zdevice" instead of "device." Thanks!

Comment: Thanks also on the other - I mixed up some of my code in the creation of my question. Services me right for posting so hastily without taking time to look over it.